# Alternatives for Enterprise Library Authorization Provider

Tags: c#, asp.net, enterprise-library

I have a ASP.NET project in which the Authorization rules are defined by extending the AuthorizationProvider abstract class which comes under Microsoft Enterprise Library. When I go to its [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.practices.enterpriselibrary.security.authorizationprovider.aspx) it says `This content is outdated and is no longer being maintained.`
In order to extend the current functionality i'm planning to change the authorization provider to something new.

1. Is using Microsoft Enterprise Library not recommended for users and roles authentication
2. Why is Authroization Provider of Microsoft Enterprise Library is outdated
3. What are the alternatives for Authorization Provider

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right - Security Application Block from Enterprise Library is outdate and will not be supported.
http://entlib.codeplex.com/discussions/496727

> ...The Security Application Block has been deprecated and removed from
>   the Enterprise Library 6 release (along with the Caching Application
>   Block and the Cryptography Application Block). I recommend reading On
>   deprecation for the approach the team has taken. Perhaps Windows
>   Identity Foundation can provide the functionality you need?...

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/agile/archive/2011/04/08/on-deprecation.aspx

> ...Similarly, with all the improvements in the security stack that have
>   been added to the platform and the latest WIF developments, the
>   Security Application Block no longer provides much additional value.
>   Therefore, it is quite likely to be also deprecated in a future...
>   version of EntLib. We are currently assessing the deprecation path.

As they are recommending, one of the alternative is use WIF that was merged into .NET 4.5 if you are able to migrate. If you aren't able to migrate then just stay with Entlib 5